# How to live check a NSTextField - Swift OS X

Tags: macos, label, swift2, nstextfield

I am currently making an OS X application written in Swift. What I want to do is when the user enters text in a `NSTextField`, I want to run a function that checks the value and adds it to a Label. How would I do this in swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Conforms `ViewController` to protocol `NSTextDelegate`.
2. Assign `ViewController` as Delegate for `TextField`.
3. Implement `controlTextDidChange` method.

   ```
   import Cocoa

   @NSApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate {

       @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
       @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
       @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!


       func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
       {
           textField.delegate = self
       }

       override func controlTextDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
       {
           let object = notification.object as! NSTextField
           self.label.stringValue = object.stringValue
       }

       func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
           // Insert code here to tear down your application
       }
   }
   ```

in ViewController:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var label2: NSTextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var textField2: NSTextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func controlTextDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let txtFld = notification.object as? NSTextField {
         switch txtFld.tag {
         case 201:
            self.label.stringValue = txtFld.stringValue
         case 202:
            self.label2.stringValue = txtFld.stringValue
         default:
            break
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Will try later. How would I detect the label that was edited (I may have 2 at one point)

Comment: Use Tags, that allow you to identify particular controls. Tag values set in Interface Builder

Comment: The code needs to inherit from NSTextFieldDelegate and not NSTextDelegate. You also need to set the text fields delegate to self.

Comment: You just create a methods in the AppDelegate, and I offered to do it in the ViewController

Comment: ViewController wasn't in the edits before which is why I couldn't do it.

Comment: I had to add NSTextFieldDelegate in ViewController, in order to receive controlTextDidChange notifications.

Answer (score 4):

swift 5 xcode 10

```
//TODO: move oin a better place?
extension NSTextField{ func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification){} }


    class TracksController:NSViewController,
        NSTextFieldDelegate
    {
...
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Search bar:
        self.searchBar.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(controlTextDidChange(_:)),
                                               name: NSTextView.didChangeSelectionNotification,
                                               object: nil)

    }
```

//MARK:  NSTextFieldDelegate

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification)
{
    guard let object = obj.object as? NSTextView else{
        return
    }


    let delegate = object.delegate
    guard  let searchField = delegate as? NSSearchField else {
        return
    }

    let text = searchField.stringValue
    print(text)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it’s been answered some while ago but I did eventually find this solution for macOS in Swift 3 (it doesn’t work for Swift 4 unfortunately) which notifies when a textfield is clicked inside and for each key stroke.

Add this delegate to your class:-

```
NSTextFieldDelegate
```

In viewDidLoad()

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textDidChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSTextViewDidChangeSelection, object: nil)
```

Then add this function:-

```
    func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("Its come here textDidChange")
        guard (notification.object as? NSTextView) != nil else { return }
        let numberOfCharatersInTextfield: Int = textFieldCell.accessibilityNumberOfCharacters()
        print("numberOfCharatersInTextfield = \(numberOfCharatersInTextfield)")
}
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above dont work for swift 4 so,

**Solution for Swift 4**

The process is mostly the same but you just have to extend some functionality to the **NSTextfield** Class. The reason we have to do this is that the delegate protocol methods like **controlTextDidChange:** actually don't exist at all because of the old design of objective-c code that doesn't map well to swift. The NSTextFieldDelegate in objective-c is an informal protocol which is the same thing as an extension in swift.

**Example**

```
extension NSTextField{ func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification){} }

class SomeViewController:NSViewController,NSTextFieldDelegate {

override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification)
{
    let object = obj.object as! NSTextField
    let value = object.stringValue
    print(value)
}
```

For every function, you want to use from the NSTextFieldDelegate just put the method in the extension clause.

Comment: Hi! I thought this answer was helpful. However it missed a step, remember to put "textfield.delegate = self" into your ViewController (else your textfield will not report changes to your ViewController).

Comment: Yes, you are correct thanks. If you wanna make the edits you can, but it kind of a given.

Comment: @user3722523 What do you mean? Where do i mention that?

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you want to trim Ex: Email ID, please use the below code.

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    emailTextField.delegate = self
  }
}

extension ViewController : NSTextFieldDelegate {
func controlTextDidBeginEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
    print(#function)
}

func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
    print(#function)
}

func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    print(#function)
    if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField {
        let givenText = textField.stringValue
        
        //Here you add other types of white space
        let possibleWhiteSpace: NSArray = [" ", "\t", "\n\r", "\n","\r"]
        var string: String = givenText as String
        possibleWhiteSpace.enumerateObjects { (whiteSpace, idx, stop) -> Void in
            string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: whiteSpace as! String, with: "") as String
        }
        
        print(string)
        emailTextField.stringValue = string as String
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
  func removeAllTypesOfWhiteSpaces(_ inputString : String) -> String {
    //Here you add other types of white space
    let possibleWhiteSpace: NSArray = [" ","\t", "\n\r", "\n","\r"]
    var outputStr: String = inputString as String
    possibleWhiteSpace.enumerateObjects { (whiteSpace, idx, stop) -> Void in
        outputStr = outputStr.replacingOccurrences(of: whiteSpace as! String, with: "") as String
    }
    return outputStr
  }
}

extension LoginViewController : NSTextFieldDelegate {
  func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField {
        let givenText = textField.stringValue
        let resultStr = givenText.removeAllTypesOfWhiteSpaces(givenText)
        textField.stringValue = resultStr as String
    }
  }
}
```