# macOS App: Don't Let Sync Changes Overwrite User Typing

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit

*Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2, Realm 3.12 (database)*

I have a Mac app where multiple users collaborate and the data syncs across multiple devices. So data is always changing.

Throughout the app, I write code that updates the UI when a sync occurs in the background. A problem I keep running into is that when a user is typing in an `NSTextField`, a sync will happen (from another user's changes) and the `NSTextField` where they are typing will suddenly revert to the new sync value, and the user will lose what they typed.

Here is a demo Mac app I put together that simulates the problem. If you start typing in the field, every 10 seconds the field updates: https://d.pr/f/8iXjqx

I'm wondering what strategies other Mac devs have used to avoid these collisions.

Is there a way to tell an `NSTextField` to not update if there is a cursor present in it? Do I have to save the value to my local database with every keystroke and then somehow do a merge when a sync happens?

Comment: If you are looking for a simple way then maybe [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716374/499581) might work. You would basically check to see if the textfield was active and if so don't update it until focus has ended. Really though for this type of thing to actually work you'd almost need a `git` type of methodology implemented so users wouldn't constantly overwrite each others changes.

Comment: How are the updates passed up to the UI? Are you using Realm notifications to update your UI?

Comment: @Giles Yes, I'm using Realm notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your textFields I would catch whether or not you are active:

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool
    {
        isFirstResponder = true
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool
    {
        isFirstResponder = false
        return super.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Then when you go to update the text, leave it if that flag is set.

Assuming you don't want to merge the text in some way, refresh the text to the model value if no edits have been made when you resign, otherwise write the change back to the model.